# Activity crashed due to memory overflow

Tags: android, memory, android-activity

Here is my code for setting wallpaper in which I have integrated admob intertitial but when I press back and go to another activity it crashes. Help me. And my logcat is showing error on setContentView(R.layout.activity_x4);

```
public class X4Activity extends Activity implements AdListener,
    OnClickListener {

ImageView display, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10;
int to;
Button set, save, rate;
InterstitialAd interstitial;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_x4);

    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this, "a15270cbf9bb519");


    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();


    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);


    interstitial.setAdListener(this);
    to = R.drawable.x24;

    display = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.zimage);
    c1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.x1);
    c2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.x2);
    c3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.x3);
    c4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.x4);
    c5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.x5);
    c6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.x6);
    c7 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.x7);
    c8 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.x8);
    c9 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.x9);
    c10 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.x10);
    rate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rate);
    set = (Button) findViewById(R.id.set);
    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);

    c1.setOnClickListener(this);
    c2.setOnClickListener(this);
    c3.setOnClickListener(this);
    c4.setOnClickListener(this);
    c5.setOnClickListener(this);
    c6.setOnClickListener(this);
    c7.setOnClickListener(this);
    c8.setOnClickListener(this);
    c9.setOnClickListener(this);
    c10.setOnClickListener(this);

    set.setOnClickListener(this);

    rate.setOnClickListener(this);
    save.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onReceiveAd(Ad ad) {
    Log.d("OK", "Received ad");
    if (ad == interstitial) {
        interstitial.show();
    }
}


public void onClick(View v) {

    String fName;
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.x1:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.x24);
        to = R.drawable.x24;
        break;
    case R.id.x2:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.x25);
        to = R.drawable.x25;
        break;

    case R.id.x3:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.x26);
        to = R.drawable.x26;
        break;
    case R.id.x4:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.x27);
        to = R.drawable.x27;
        break;
    case R.id.x5:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.x28);
        to = R.drawable.x28;
        break;
    case R.id.x6:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.x29);
        to = R.drawable.x29;
        break;
    case R.id.x7:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.x30);
        to = R.drawable.x30;
        break;
    case R.id.x8:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.x31);
        to = R.drawable.x31;
        break;
    case R.id.x9:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.x32);
        to = R.drawable.x32;
        break;
    case R.id.x10:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.x33);
        to = R.drawable.x33;
        break;

    case R.id.set:

        ***********
    case R.id.save:
        **********

}

}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   X4Activity.this.finish();
}
@Override
public void onDismissScreen(Ad arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad arg0, ErrorCode arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onLeaveApplication(Ad arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void onPresentScreen(Ad arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Comment: Please show the stacktrace, so we can see the exact error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that you know why you need this, couldyou please tell me why do you need:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   X4Activity.this.finish();
}
```

You are thus terminating your "main" Activity.

Comment: This just duplicates what the default superclass implementation of `onBackPressed()` does and isn't the problem.

Comment: Then the StackTrace is absolutely necessary.

Comment: as m a beginner in android can you tell me what is stacktrace? logcat?

Comment: Ok in brief - if you're using Eclipse (default look - JAVA) - to the right there's a TAB called LogCat, where the stacktrace is situated. For more information about what a stacktrace is - refer to a search engine, but that's an essential part of the programming. Don't tell me that you don't know what a debug is too, please.